# Map of smooth curves and its separability degree

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

I'm interested in a proof of the following fact from *Silverman: Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*:

Let $\Phi: C_1 \rightarrow C_2$ be a nonconstant map of smooth curves. Then for all but finitely many  $Q \in C_2$:

$ \# \Phi^{-1}(Q) = deg_s (\Phi)$,

where $ deg_s (\Phi)$ is the separability degree of $\Phi$.

In particular, I'd prefer to see a proof not using the notion of schemes as a) I've not worked with schemes yet, b) I need this statement for a presentation where most the audience isn't familiary with the notion of schemes.

Also I'd love to see a geometric interpretation of the statement (why only for *nearly* all points).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: There is certainly a proof of this in Shafarevich Volume 1 (the section on finite morphisms), which doesn't use scheme language. About the last question: well, it's only true for nearly all points because of _ramification_. For example think about $\mathbf{A}^1 \rightarrow \mathbf{A}^1$ defined by $x \mapsto x^2$. This map has degree 2, but the point $0$ in the target has only one point in its preimage. Does that address your question?

Comment: Do you happen to know which chapter in Shafarevich this would be? Spontaniously, I don't seem able to find the statement.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have my copy to hand, but I am fairly certain that in the section where finite morphisms are defined, he then proves exactly the theorem above. I think it's in Chapter 1.

Comment: Maybe I should be a little more careful with my pronouncements: the proof in Shafarevich only deals with characteristic zero (or separable maps). I think it's helpful to understand that case first of course, but if your issue is specifically to understand non-separable maps, this source won't give you what you need.

Comment: Does Silverman uses schemes in this book ? For the inseparable case, decompose $C_1\to C_2$ into $C_1\to C_3\to C_2$ with the first map purely inseparable (i.e. the extension of function fields $k(C_3)\to k(C_1)$ is purely inseparable) and $C_3\to C_2$ is separable. Notice that $C_1\to C_3$ is then a homeomorphism.

Comment: No, Silverman doesn't proof the statement at all, but links to Hartshorne (who uses schemes and I don't even see how the statement follows from the cited theorem)

Comment: @Cantlog: thanks for the help with the inseparable case. But how can I see that $C_1 \rightarrow C_3$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: You can use the same idea as in the proof of "Marie" to reduced to a statement on Dedekind domains. In the purely inseparable case, the decomposition of $\mathfrak p B=\mathfrak q^e$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really avoid the commutative algebra. You can avoid talking about schemes, but you're not getting out of the commutative algebra.

This follows from two things: first, from the famous $n = \sum ef$ formula: if $B/A$ is a finite separable extension of Dedekind domains, of degree $n$, and $\mathfrak p$ is a prime of $A$ which decomposes in $B$ as

$$\mathfrak p B = \mathfrak q_1^{e_1} \dots  \mathfrak q_r^{e_r},$$

then $n = \sum_{i=0}^r e_if_i$, where $f_i = [B/\mathfrak q_i : A/\mathfrak p]$ is the degree of the residue class field extension. Second, it follows from the fact that finitely many primes of $A$ ramify in $B$.

Now suppose that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are smooth *affine* curves over an algebraically closed field $k$, with coordinate rings $B$ and $A$ respectively. The rings $B$ and $A$ are Dedekind domains and they are $k$-algebras. Their nonzero primes correspond to points on the respective curves. Since $k$ is algebraically closed the residue class field extensions $B/\mathfrak q$ of $A/\mathfrak p$ is trivial (both identify with $k$). It follows that whenever $\mathfrak p \subseteq A$ is not ramified, we have $r=n$.

For a morphism of projective curves, we just use an open affine cover to reduce it to the affine case.

Remark that this can fail badly for non-smooth curves. For instance, if $C$ is the nodal cubic $y^2 = x^3-x^2$, the rational parametrization $y=t(t^2-1),x = t^2-1$ is a morphism $\mathbf A^1 \to C$ which has degree $2$, but almost all fibres have a single point in them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although it uses statements we hadn't had in our lecture of Algebraic Number Theory or the one of Geometry yet, it still seems a lot easier to "understand" to me then schemes.
For the inseparable case, would you also suggest to factor the map in a purely inseparable and a separable map, as Cantlog above suggested in the comments? And how exactly can I use an open affine cover and reduce to the affine case for projective curves? I'm sorry for my maybe slow understanding, but I just started studying geometry some days ago, hence I am not very profound with the techniques.

Comment: @Louis You are welcome. What Cantlog says is correct. To reduce to the affine case, take an open affine $U$ in $C_2$, and consider the map restricted to the inverse image of $C_2$. It is a fact that this inverse image is affine. 

Don't worry about your speed. Algebraic geometry takes time to learn. It's okay if at first you can't justify everything. As you learn more, the pieces will come together.

Comment: Sorry for bothering again, but it still doesn't seem clear for me why from the map $C_1 \rightarrow C_3$ purely inseparable it already follows that it has to be 1-to-1. Is this a geometric argument or also an argument of number theory? My algebraic NT book here seems to talk about separable extensions of dedekind domains only.

Comment: Dear @Louis, no problem! It is normal that an algebraic number theory book should be concerned mostly with separable extensions since $\mathbf Q$ is perfect. The inseparable case only happens when the base field has char. p. I believe that you would most benefit by looking at an example. Take $F$ to be the algebraic closure of $\mathbf F_p$, and consider the curve $y^p -x =0$ lying over $\mathbf A^1_F$. Can you see that the map $(x,y) \mapsto x$ is one-to-one? This follows from the fact that every element of $F$ has a unique $p$-th root. And this is, esentially, the "only" example!

Comment: I see why this map is one-to-one. Also, it seems to correspond with $y \mapsto y^p$ the Frobeniusmorphism. Is this a coincidence? But how/why is this the "only" case? Thanks again!

Comment: @Louis You are welcome. It is the "only" case because any purely-inseparable extension is obtained by adding a $p$-power root of the base field, in an analogous fashion (here we added the $p$-th root of $x$, namely $y$). Also, I don't think that it is a coincidence. It is essentially the [absolute Frobenius morphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism#The_absolute_Frobenius_morphism), a construction which generalizes the Frobenius endomorphism of a finite field.